# OpenCV C++: How to slow down background adaptation of BackgroundSubtractorMOG?

Tags: c++, opencv, background-subtraction

I am using BackgroundSubtractorMOG in OpenCV to track objects. When they appear, it works fine but the background fastly adapts so I cannot track static objects. How can I make the background adaptation slower (I dont want it fully static, just slower)?

Setting the learning rate using the constructor doesn't change that:

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG pBSMOG = BackgroundSubtractorMOG(???);
```

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG pBSMOG = BackgroundSubtractorMOG(int history=200, int nmixtures=5, double backgroundRatio=0.7, double noiseSigma=0);
```

Where,

- **history** – Length of the history.
- **nmixtures** – Number of Gaussian mixtures.
- **backgroundRatio** – Background ratio.
- **noiseSigma** – Noise strength (standard deviation of the brightness or each color channel).     0 means some automatic value.

Increasing the `history` value will slow down the adaptation rate.

There is another function available in OpenCV:

```
Ptr <BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(int
history=500, double varThreshold=16, bool detectShadows=true )
```

This is much faster than the previous one and it can eleminate detecting shadows too.

Comment: BackgroundSubtractorMOG pBSMOG = BackgroundSubtractorMOG(int) doesnt match the function prototype

Comment: Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG> createBackgroundSubtractorMOG(int history=200, int nmixtures=5, double backgroundRatio=0.7, double noiseSigma=0)